# Why is this SingleChildScrollView is not working in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a scrollable list but for some reason I can't scroll it. I got the code from an example but seems like it does not work in my app. The code looks like:

```
Container(
            color: Colors.red,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hel2lo"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hel7lo"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hel8lo"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),
                      ]
                  )
              )
          )
```

and I can't scroll:

[image]

Comment: what is the partent of your container ?

Comment: try to give your container some height

Comment: Show more code, the problem can be in your parent widget.

Comment: Giving height to the container helped. Thanks. Is there any way to set the height based on how much is left for it?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using a Column. If that's the case, and assuming you want the scroll to fill the remaining space on the screen, you can wrap the Container in an Expanded.

Answer (score 0):

If you **wrap** your widget with an **expanded** widget then your code will work as expected

> an example code:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Text('some text'),
      Text('some another text'),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: new SingleChildScrollView(
                child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hel2lo"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hel7lo"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hel8lo"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hel8lo"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
              Text("hello"),
            ]))),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use SingleChildScrollView in a container.
Or try to give height value to the container.